# How to run deno compiled executable on a mac?

Tags: macos, deno

I am able to create PC and Mac executables from Windows 10 with Deno just fine:

```
"deno.exe" compile --unstable --allow-all --target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc --output myapp_x86pc myapp.js  

"deno.exe" compile --unstable --allow-all --target x86_64-apple-darwin --output myapp_x86mac myapp.js  

"deno.exe" compile --unstable --allow-all --target aarch64-apple-darwin --output myapp_aarchmac myapp.js
```

But how to actually test and run the produced binary on a Mac? Does the file need a specific extension, or does it perhaps need to be packaged or signed somehow in order to run?

Trying to run the myapp_x86mac through finder results in a dialog about unknown developer id, and I can seemingly add a security exception, but it still won't run. And trying to run it from terminal just results in zsh: Permission denied.

Is it even possible to create a working Deno OSX executable without full Apple development environment? I don't own a Mac or Apple ID for that matter, and need a loaner Mac to do testing, so I can't mess too much with the machine. I just want something that is easy to distribute and run on various machines, but for limited audience so I would like to avoid full Apple Store publishing "experience".

Comment: The file may need to have execute permission added (`chmod +x /path/to/binary`) and/or quarantine restriction removed (`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/binary`). Running `ls -leO@ /path/to/binary` will give you more info about its permissions and attributes. You may find more info about macOS application security by searching at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) as well as Stackexchange.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you, execute permission bit sounds like could be potential culprit. It's been couple of years since I have messed with linux type of systems, so I didn't think about that. I tried to explore the mac file properties UI and the permissions there but that seemed to be more ACL like and had only read/write control. I'll try the chmod/xattr approach once I can loan the mac again :)

Comment: The Finder's Info window gives a simplified view of file permissions, and just leaves out some things like most flags and xattrs; `ls -leO@` gives a much more complete picture.

Comment: @GordonDavisson you were on point, problem was as simple as needing to set the execute permission with `chmod +x` !

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, no. You need to have **XCODE installed** or **at least the XCODE commandline** tools.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem with `chmod +x`, no XCODE needed.

Comment: Interesting. I got this answer straight from the developers in the Discord chat.